# How to delete multi-level map

Tags: go

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "level": "WARN",
    "line": "247",
    "data": {
        "activeAddons": [
            {
                "name": "Measure",
                "type": 0
            }
        ],
        "code": "Sample",
        "id": 40,
        "name": "Sample TEST"
    },
    "method": "valid-clx"
}
```

With the following go code.

```
var cache map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(res), &cache)
token := cache["token"]

delete(cache, "line")
delete(cache, "data[activeAddons]")
```

I can delete the map/interface of "line", and "data" if I remove `activeAddons`. The problem is, I wanted to delete only `data[activeAddons]`.

Is this possible? Or I need to find another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes this is possible, but you first have to receive `data` and tell go that this is also a map.

```
delete(cache, "line")
delete(cache["data"].(map[string]interface{}), "activeAddons")
```